# XSLT style-sheet query to transform the XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xsl.
  I need to write a xslt code to transform a below xml code
        If i have a count of 'LongCallService' tag is more than 2 then
        I need to select this First 'LongCallService' tag and check weather it contain 'inviceCode' sub child element tag inside 'chargeGroup' or not !! if yes then needs to dispaly. Please help.

XML code:

```
  <RelatedCharges>
<CVOIP>
//other child element</<CVOIP>>
<Internet>
//other child element</Internet>

<LongCallService>
    <chargeGroup>
    <InvoiceCode>some number</InvoiceCode>
    </chargeGroup>      
</LongCallService>

<LongCallService>
//other child element(child Structure same as above first sibling)</LongCallService>
<LongCallService>
//other child element(child Structure same as above first sibling)</LongCallService>
</RelatedCharges>
```

Comment: "*If i have a count of 'LongCallService' tag is more than 2 then ...*" And if not? "*check weather it contain 'inviceCode' sub child element tag inside 'chargeGroup' or not !! if yes then ...*" And if not?

Comment: Please note that in your example, the `<InvoiceCode>` is **NOT** inside `<chargeGroup>`.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your description, I have created an XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelatedCharges>
    <CVOIP> //other child element</CVOIP>
    <Internet>//other child element</Internet>

    <LongCallService>
        <chargeGroup>
            <Code></Code>
        </chargeGroup>
        <InvoiceCode>some number</InvoiceCode>
    </LongCallService>

    <LongCallService>//other child element</LongCallService>

    <LongCallService>//other child element</LongCallService>
</RelatedCharges>
```

when this stylesheet is applied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="count(RelatedCharges/LongCallService) &gt; 2">
            <xsl:copy-of select="RelatedCharges/LongCallService[1][chargeGroup/InvoiceCode]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs **nothing**, but if the first `<LongCallService>` is as follows:

```
    <LongCallService>
        <chargeGroup>
            <Code></Code>
        <InvoiceCode>some number</InvoiceCode>
        </chargeGroup>
    </LongCallService>
```

it outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LongCallService>
   <chargeGroup>
      <Code/>
      <InvoiceCode>some number</InvoiceCode>
   </chargeGroup>
</LongCallService>
```

Comment: Why does your 2nd `<LongCallService>` element have a structure that is different from the 1st one (and the one in the OP)?

Comment: I have intentionally created a second `<LongCallService>` with `<InvoiceCode>` inside `<chargeGroup>` to create an output. His sample wont create an output.

Comment: Well, I don't see the logic in that myself, but I believe you should at least state explicitly that you're changing the rules of the game. He specifically asked for the invoice code from the **first** `<LongCallService>` tag, **if it exists** inside `<chargeGroup>`. His sample creates an empty output - just as he requested.

Comment: I forgot that he wants to get the first `<LongCallService>`. I'll edit my answer, thanks!

Comment: IMHO, the question is poorly formulated and you are wasting your time trying to answer it in its current form.

Comment: I have seen the OP edited his/her question a lot of times. He/she tried his/her best explaining the problem as best as he/she can. I just hoped that I can meet him/her halfway.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel to understand .
@michael.hor257k : I tried hard to form a question properly . I just shared the little part of the requirement.Basically I have complete existing style sheet where i need to add piece of code to achieve specific task, unfortunately due to lack of knowledge in xslt i'm facing so much pain to do simple things :(